# How should I assert that the checkbox is checked in Cypress?

Tags: javascript, typescript, selenium, cypress, ui-automation

I am trying to assert on an element to see if the checkbox is checked or not. Please find the image below:

[image]

Now, this is the dom structure to target this element:

```
<pds-radio class data-v-1234bb3c model="singleSelection" checked>
 #shadow-root (open)
 <div class="wrapper">
  <div class="radio-wrapper">
          <div class="radio-container">
                 <div class="radio active" tabindex="0">
                        ::before
```

Right now when I click on it, I get this 'checked' attribute in **'pds-radio'** and in the shadow the class becomes **class="radio active"** if not checked it's **class="radio"**

I will really appreciate your help on this. Thanks

Comment: Add id on element you want to check and get the element by id not by class

Comment: I am able to click on the element and it gets selected, but after that I want to check if it actually got selected (This is the assertion that I am looking to perform for which I posted the DOM structure).

Comment: I was hoping to get a solution by using shadow function and then check if it has class active radio.

Comment: I hope this will help https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/should#Function

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[You can use `.shadow()`](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/shadow#Syntax) to access the shadow DOM.

```
cy.get('pds-radio')
  .shadow()
  .find('.radio')
  .should('have.class', 'active')
```

Alternatively, you could include the `includeShadowDom` option in the `find` command.